# phpmysql retrieving multiple data using join show last row result only

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have use joins to retrieve the data from various tables and I am successful in it but when I want to retrieve it the query only show me the result of last row even though I have use while loop on it but its not working properly give me the one result only which belongs to last row .
Here is my php scrip.

```
include("connections/conn.php");
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `tbl_cart` as c join " . 
                                  "`tbl_product` as p join " . 
                                  "`tbl_catagory` as ca join " . 
                                  "`tbl_compony` as co join " . 
                                  "`tbl_images` as i " . 
                                  "on c.pid=p.pro_id " . 
                                  "and p.compony=co.com_id " . 
                                  "and p.catagory=ca.cat_id " . 
                                  "and p.pro_id=i.p_id");   
$row = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
    $product_ids[]=$row1['pro_id'];
    foreach($product_ids as $pro) {
        echo $pro;
    }
}
```

but the array contains this data. which have more result of from similar columns.

> `111Array ( [0] => 33 [cart_id] => 33 [1] => 110 [pid] => 110 [2] => 20 [quantity] => 20 [3] => 65,000 [price] => 65,000 [4] => 9 [userid] => 9 [5] => 2014-08-14 [dated] => 2013-08-24 [6] => 110 [pro_id] => 110 [7] => Aspire S3-391 [title] => Aspire S3-391 [8] => 10.68 lbs [weight] => 10.68 lbs [9] => 15.90 inch [width] => 15.90 inch [10] => 2.31 cm [height] => 2.31 cm [11] => Black [color] => Black [12] => 65,000 [13] => $1499 [USD] => $1499 [14] => [waranty] => [15] => Make work a touch easier.Get in touch with your productive side. Tap and scroll your way through the workday with an intuitive touch screen (select models) that helps you work so much smarter. Count on durability inside and out from built in security to the spill resistant keyboard and a thin light design thats packed with style. [description] => Make work a touch easier.Get in touch with your productive side. Tap and scroll your way through the workday with an intuitive touch screen (select models) that helps you work so much smarter. Count on durability inside and out from built in security to the spill resistant keyboard and a thin light design thats packed with style. [16] => 1 [catagory] => 1 [17] => 4 [compony] => 4 [18] => Intel® Core™ i5 [l_ptype] => Intel® Core™ i5 [19] => 2.8 GHZ [l_pspeed] => 2.8 GHZ [20] => 700 GB [l_harddisk] => 700 GB [21] => 4GB DDR3 [l_RAM] => 4GB DDR3 [22] => Windows 8 [l_op] => Windows 8 [23] => [l_battery] => [24] => [lcd_brightness] => [25] => [lcd_contrast] => [26] => [lcd_imagesize] => [27] => [lcd_pixelsize] => [28] => [lcd_resolution] => [29] => [lcd_backlight] => [30] => [lcd_depth] => [31] => [p_pspeed] => [32] => [p_resolution] => [33] => [p_pconsumption] => [34] => [p_memorycapacity] => [35] => [p_storagecapacity] => [36] => [p_interface] => [37] => [p_processorspeed] => [38] => [pro_p_consumption] => [39] => [pro_brightness] => [40] => [pro_resolution] => [41] => [pro_imagesize] => [42] => [pro_ptype] => [43] => [pro_imagesignal] => [44] => [pro_contrast] => [45] => [sca_capacity] => [46] => [sca_speed] => [47] => [sca_colordepth] => [48] => [sca_usb] => [49] => [sca_documentsize] => [50] => [sca_resolution] => [51] => 2013-08-24 [52] => 1 [cat_id] => 1 [53] => Laptop [cat_title] => Laptop [54] => 4 [com_id] => 4 [55] => Acer [com_title] => Acer [56] => 120 [img_id] => 120 [57] => Aspire S3-391_main.jpg [main_image] => Aspire S3-391_main.jpg [58] => Aspire S3-391_left.jpg [left_image] => Aspire S3-391_left.jpg [59] => Aspire S3-391_right.jpg [right_image] => Aspire S3-391_right.jpg [60] => Aspire S3-391_top.jpg [top_image] => Aspire S3-391_top.jpg [61] => Aspire S3-391_other.jpg [other_image] => Aspire S3-391_other.jpg [62] => 110 [p_id] => 110 )`

And when I run this query in sql it returns me two rows so how can I retrieve the data accordingly in my php script I am really confuse in it please help me out .
Now for further understanding i am adding this picture. And you people can see that this query is returning me two rows so how will fetch the two rows separately in my php script and show them on my page.
[image: sql picture]

Comment: Why should it output anything else? You only save one value from your query result, and you try to echo out the entire saved array each time. 1st iteration: 1 row of output. 2nd iteration = 2 rows of output, etc...

Comment: but i am confuse that how will i differentiate that this is 1st row and this is second and how can i retrieve the data which belongs to first row and which one belongs to second row i am confuse please help me out

Comment: and array is just dummy i have print_r($sql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are fetching the results from the same variable which bring you to a logical error see what's happening here you fetch once the result and store it in `$row` so first row from the result set get fetched and again your fetching the record and storing in another variable but from the same variable `$sql` and applying the while loop in result you are getting only one row because the first row get skipped.

Solution: Do not fetch the Results from the same variable make another variable and store the same query in it if you really needed e.g

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `tbl_cart` as c join " . 
                                  "`tbl_product` as p join " . 
                                  "`tbl_catagory` as ca join " . 
                                  "`tbl_compony` as co join " . 
                                  "`tbl_images` as i " . 
                                  "on c.pid=p.pro_id " . 
                                  "and p.compony=co.com_id " . 
                                  "and p.catagory=ca.cat_id " . 
                                  "and p.pro_id=i.p_id");   

$sql1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `tbl_cart` as c join " . 
                                  "`tbl_product` as p join " . 
                                  "`tbl_catagory` as ca join " . 
                                  "`tbl_compony` as co join " . 
                                  "`tbl_images` as i " . 
                                  "on c.pid=p.pro_id " . 
                                  "and p.compony=co.com_id " . 
                                  "and p.catagory=ca.cat_id " . 
                                  "and p.pro_id=i.p_id");   
$row    =   mysql_fetch_array($sql);
while($row1= mysql_fetch_array($sql1))
{
    echo $row1['pro_id'];
    }
```

I hope this will work.

Comment: so next time remember this mistake

Answer (score 1):

You have this statement:

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
```

That will fetch the "first" from the resultset (if there's at least one row).

Then you have a while loop, that does another fetch:

```
$row1 = mysql_fetch_array($sql)
```

That will get the "second" and following row. (Since you've already retrieved the first row.)

If you don't want to "skip" that first row, then remove this line from your code:

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
```

Comment: but is that not annoying I thought that my query is returning both the rows and storing in a $sql .and please tell me one more thing how can I store both the rows in $sql

Comment: but when I count the $row it is returning me 2 rows

Comment: Your `$sql` variable is a reference to a **resultset** returned by the query (a "resource" in PHP parlance). (A bit bizarre to name the variable `$sql`, the normal pattern is to name that variable something like `$result` or `$rs`). Your code should include a test to check whether that return value, to see if an error was returned, before you issue a fetch. If an error has occurred `mysql_query()` will return FALSE, otherwise, for a SELECT statement, it returns a resource. The "while fetch" loop is the normal pattern. NOTE mysql interface is DEPRECATED, new development should use mysqli or PDO

Comment: If you were using the newer **mysqli** interface (instead of the deprecated mysql interface), you could use the **mysqli_store_result** get all of the rows in one fell swoop, rather than having to individually fetch each row.

Comment: The normal pattern (with a mysql resultset) is to fetch the next row, process it, fetch the next row, process it, etc. until all rows have been processed. If you want to defer processing of the resultset, your processing in the loop could be as simple as storing each row as an element in a array. Then later, you can use a loop to process the elements from the array. (This approach is not memory efficient for large resultsets; a more efficient approach is to process the row in the fetch loop, and not store all of the rows.)

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be logicial to get only last row result.
If inside the While loop, you put `"echo 'in the loop';"`, you'll probably see that two times.

But as you do:

```
'$product_ids[]=$row1['pro_id'];'
```

you fill `$product_ids[]` first time with `$row1['pro_id']` and, at next loop, you fill it again with the new value, destroying the first one.

In fact, you're making a common mistake and I suppose I understand what you want to do:

1. loop to getresult
2. display result

using

```
foreach($product_ids as $pro) {
    echo $pro;
```

But you have put the foreach inside the while loop as it must be outside.
A most simple and understable way would be:

```
`$index=0;
while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
    $product_ids[$index]=$row1['pro_id'];
    $index++;
}

foreach($product_ids as $pro) {
        echo $pro;
    }
}`
```

A detail: use another MySQL Driver, like `mysqli` as `mysql` basic driver is obsolote.

Comment: And still I have the same result as I have before

Comment: i have apply MySQL_num_rows($sql) and it is returning me 2 as a result it means my query is returning 2 rows but why i am unable to show 2 results

Comment: Vicky, inside the while loop, just get the result and "echo" it (in my code, just add echo $product_ids[$index]; just BEFORE index++) You'll see that you have the two results. The problem is not the result you get. The problem is the way you put the result in the variable. Regards.